# Accessing Many to Many relationship in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have set up a few models as follows:

Page

Gallery

Image

Gallery and Image share a many to many relationship.

Page can have 1 or 0 galleries.

I have created a gallery with a few images and attached it to a page object.

However, I'm having trouble displaying it in a template.

Can anyone help?

My page view looks like this:

```
def detail(request, page_id):
p = get_object_or_404(Page, pk=page_id)
return render_to_response('page/detail.html', {'page': p},
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And the template:

```
{% block images %}
{% if page.gallery %}
{% for image in page.gallery.image_set.all %}
<a rel="gallery" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ image.image }}"></a>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}`
```

If I try to output some text within the IF block it comes out OK but not within the loop.

Any advice on getting it to work / generally tidying this up would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `Gallery-Image` relationship is many to many I'm guessing you have an `m2m` field on your `Gallery` model, where the m2m manager is the field itself. The manager can be queried just like any other `QuerySet`: `model_instance.mym2mfield.filter()`.

If your `ManyToManyField` is called `images` on the `Gallery` model, your template would look like this:

```
{% for image in page.gallery.images.all %}
    <a rel="gallery" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ image.image }}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

If your `ManyToManyField` is on your `Image` model, the default name would be as you describe, unless you specified a `related_name` in which case you'd use that name.

```
{% for image in page.gallery.image_set.all %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may lie in the way you're accessing the gallery from the page.  In your template, try something like the following and see if you get any output:

```
{{ page.gallery }}
```

There are instances where certain errors may get ignored in a template.

Also, I'm a little curious how your Page and Gallery are related?  Does the Page model have a OneToOneField called "gallery"? Does Gallery have a ForeignKey to Page? In the latter case, you'd access the galleries associated with a page by:

```
{{ page.gallery_set.all }}
```

It would be easier to answer this question if you provided some additional information about the fields on your models.